# Should I write a separate method for any possible parameter value

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I am very new to unit testing concept and I stick with writing my first one.

I have a method for normalize ID value. It should return passed value for any positive number (even if it is string with number inside) and zero (0) for any other passed value.

```
function normalizeId($val) {
    // if $val is good positive number return $val;
    // else return 0;
}
```

I want to write a unit test for this function and have assertion to any possible arguments. For example:
`5, -5, 0, "5", "-5", 3.14, "fff", new StdClass()` etc.

Should I write a method in my TestCase class for any of this condition or have one method with all conditions on separate lines?
I.e.

```
public function testNormalizeId() {
    $this->assertEquals(5, MyClass::normalizeId(5));
    $this->assertEquals(0, MyClass::normalizeId(-5));
    $this->assertEquals(0, MyClass::normalizeId("fff"));
}
```

or

```
public function testNormalizeId_IfPositiveInt_GetPositiveInt() {
    $this->assertEquals(5, MyClass::normalizeId(5));
}
public function testNormalizeId_IfNegativeInt_GetZeroInt() {
   $this->assertEquals(0, MyClass::normalizeId(-5));
}
public function testNormalizeId_IfNotIntAsString_GetZeroInt() {
    $this->assertEquals(0, MyClass::normalizeId("fff"));
}
```

How about best practices? I hear that the second choice is good but I'm worry about very many methods for very many possible parameter values. It can be positive number, negative number, zero, string with positive number inside, string with negative number inside, string with float inside etc etc.

**Edit**

Or maybe the third approach with `provider`?

```
public function testNormalizeIdProvider()
{
    return array(
        array(5, 5),
        array(-5, 0),
        array(0, 0),
        array(3.14, 0),
        array(-3.14, 0),
        array("5", 5),
        array("-5", 0),
        array("0", 0),
        array("3.14", 0),
        array("-3.14", 0),
        array("fff", 0),
        array("-fff", 0),
        array(true, 0),
        array(array(), 0),
        array(new stdClass(), 0),
    );
}

/**
 * @dataProvider testNormalizeIdProvider
 */
public function testNormalizeId($provided, $expected)
{
    $this->assertEquals($expected, MyObject::normalizeId($provided));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very knowledgeable about PHP nor the unit testing frameworks that you can use therein, but in the general sphere of Unit Testing I'd recommend the second approach for these reasons

- Gives a specific test case fail for a particular type of input rather than having to trawl through the actual Assert failure message to figure out which one failed.
- Makes it much easier to parametrize these tests if you decide that you need to perform tests on a specific type of conversion with more than one input (e.g if you decided to have a text file containing 1,000 random strings and wanted to load these up in a test driver and run the test case for converting strings for each entry by way of functional or acceptance testing later on)
- Makes it easier to change out the individual test cases for when you need some special logic to setup
- Makes it easier to spot when you've missed a type of conversion because the method names read off easier against a checklist :)
- (Dubious) Will maybe make it easier to spot where your "god class" might be in need of internal refactoring to use separate sub-classes to perform specific types of conversions (not saying your approach is wrong but you might find the logic for one type of conversion very nasty; when you review your 20 or 30 individual test cases that could provide the impetus to bite the bullet and develop more specialized converter classes)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand this benefits but what about disadvantages?
Now I have to write 15 test methods with each possible input values (not sure that I consider all of them) just for one small method. Maybe using `provider` approach instead? I edit my question to show the third approach with provider.

Comment: @djxak, not sure what you mean by the provider approach, but in terms of disadvantages - yes, having to write 15+ test methods is a bit of a pain but I feel it is outweighed by the advantages - perhaps others will be able to provide some perspective on the first approach...

Comment: I edit my question (added third approach) but maybe this approach is specific for PHPUnit and not available in other X-Unit libraries.

Comment: @djxak ah ok that makes sense now, yes that is a fine and valid approach as well, kind of like what I mentioned re having a list of values loaded from a file.The only thing I'd suggest with method #3 is add a parameter to indicate the type of data being converted - it will make any Assertion fail messages much clearer as to what failed.

Answer (score 2):

Use the data provider, as you discovered yourself. There is no benefit in duplicating the *exact* testcase in multiple methods with only having parameters and expectations change.

Personally, I do really start with the tests all in one method for such simple cases. I'd start with a simple good case, and then gradually adding more cases. I may not feel the need to change this into a data provider instantly, because it won't pay off instantly - but on the other hand things can change, and this test structure can be a short term solution that needs refactoring.

So whenever you observe yourself adding more lines of test into such a multi test case method, stop and make it using a data provider instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a pity that I cannot accept both answers as accepted as you really complement Stephen's answer.